# Referencing to XSD group which contains xs:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I have little bit problem. In specification of XSD All element here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp is written that parent element which can be used is a GROUP where defining the group.
I have these XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:group name="DescriptionGroup">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

I will specify more groups in this file just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:group name="DescriptionGroup">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:group name="DescriptionGroup2">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="description2" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="comment2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:group name="DescriptionGroup3">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="description3" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="comment3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

Point is that group element need to use element `<xs:all>`. With definition groups I have no more problems, everything is fine, but when I need to use the groups in this content:

```
<xs:element name="tesName">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:group minOccurs="0" ref="DescriptionGroup" />
      <xs:group minOccurs="0" ref="DescriptionGroup2" />
      <xs:group minOccurs="0" ref="DescriptionGroup3" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

XSD validation throwing errors

> Error The group ref to 'all' is not the root particle, or it is being used as an extension.

but `<xs:all>` can be used at groups, exactly what I described at top.
I need in one XML file  element (testName) 3 of kind combinations like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" ?>
<testing>
  <tesName>
    <description>bla bla bla</description>
    <comment>ble ble ble</comment>
  </tesName>
  <tesName>
    <description2>bla bla bla</description>
  </tesName>
  <tesName>
    <comment3>bla bla bla</comment3>
  </tesName>
  <tesName>
    <comment2>bla bla bla</comment2>
  </tesName>
</testing>
```